# Haskell, data type function and how to extract information?

Tags: function, haskell, types, typeclass

i created two data types which let me create a "Hill" and a "MountainChain":

```
data Hill = Hill Name Size Isolation Prominence
  deriving(Eq,Show)
type Name      = String
type Size     = Float
type Isolation  = Float
type Prominence = Float

data MountainChain = MountainChain Name [Hill]
  deriving(Eq,Show)
```

Example:

```
fstHill = Hill "fstHill" 45.0 18.0 4.0

scdHill = Hill "scdHill" 222.0 60.0 15.0

output: 

*Main> fstHill
Hill "fstHill" 45.0 18.0 4.0
*Main> scdHill
Hill "scdHill" 222.0 60.0 15.0
```

My question now is how to write a function that will return the `maxSize` of an `Hill` within the `MountainChain` and a function that returns the `name` of the highest `Hill` (within the MC) with the following types:

```
mSize :: MountainChain -> Size
majorHill :: MountainChain -> Name
```

Comment: have a look at `maximumBy` using ``compare `on` something`` (where `on` is from `Data.Function`)

Comment: you probably want to combine this with a getter like `size (Hill _ sz _ _) = sz` - if you convert this into record syntax you'll get those for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `mSize` easily using pattern matching and a helper function:

```
maxSize' :: Hill -> (Size, Name)
maxSize' (Hill n s _ _) = (s, n)

maxSize :: MountainChain -> Size
maxSize (MountainChain _ mc) = fst $ maximum $ maxSize' <$> mc

majorHill :: MountainChain -> Name
majorHill (MountainChain _ mc) = snd $ maximum $ maxSize' <$> mc
```

What's happening here is that `maxSize` does a pattern match against the `Hill` type and extracts the name and size. It then takes the value of a tuple with the size as its first element (there's a reason for that, and I'll get to it in a bit).

`maxSize` just maps `maxSize'` over a `MountainChain`, which (thanks to pattern matching) is treated just like a list of `Hill`s. We then apply `maximum` over the returned list of `[(Float, String)]`. `maximum` is fortunately smart enough that it'll perform a stable sort on a list of tuples using the first element in each tuple. Finally, we extract the first element from the single tuple returned by `maximum` using `fst`.

`majorHill` once again makes use of this mechanic, but extracts the name (using `snd`) instead of the height.

Comment: This solution is very nice! I do understand your code(thanks for the explanation!), but i dont understand this `<$>` operation.

Comment: `<$>` is syntactic sugar - basically a shorthand infix version of `map`, which, unsurprisingly, maps a function to the items to a list.

Comment: Thats suprised me alot! Thanks for the new notation :)